# login session in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completely new to the python and just started to build simple web application which include login system. I am familiar to PHP. In PHP it is simple to create session as below and secure the page just by checking session. But I have search similar solution in python. All I found is either using python framework or extra library installation but the problem is I don't have any privileged in server to install anything. I can only access through FTP only. how can I implement the login system without using framework and library.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(validate_user)
{
   $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
   header('Location: adminpage.php');
}
?>
```

here is my python code

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if("login" in form):
    username = form.getvalue("username")
    password = form.getvalue("password")
    if(username=="admin" and password=="admin")
        ''' create session['username], session['password'] and redirect
```

Comment: My recommendation since you are new to python is to install python on your computer, the frameworks or needed libraries, a wsgi server (I cant recommend the cgi path), test your scripts. Then, ask the server administrator to install your stuff. If he cant, doesnt know or doesnt want, change the server. If the client doesnt agree with your way of doing things, drop the project and learn python (you will love it).

Comment: Better to use use flask framework rather than core programming in python.  Easy to understand and easy to manage login session. Simply define  session['username'] = request.form['username'] and your session will be create